# OWL axiom: Given an individual of a particular class, enforce an existence of an Object Property relation with another individual

Tags: owl, protege

In OWL, is there a way to state that an individual of a particular class must be related to another individual via a specific object property?

For example, I would like to state that:

```
forall(x) Object(x) -> exists(y) Shape(y) ^ hasShape(x, y)
```

i.e., "For all objects, there exists a shape that is the shape of the object."

so that if there is an individual of the type Object that has no shape associated with it, a reasoner would find it to be inconsistent.

I tried an axiom:

```
Object SubClassOf hasShape min 1 Shape
```

but it's not working.

It seems like the issue is because Object Property in OWL has no identity, but is there a workaround for this issue?

(I'm using Protege 5.2.0)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? And what does it mean that "Object Property in OWL has no identity"? What you write in your pseudo first order logic axiom is exactly equivalent to what you write in your OWL axiom.

Comment: A reasoner doesn't find any inconsistency in your case. OWL reasoning is about inferencing, not constraint validation. There are other approaches to handle this, e.g. Pellet ICV, SHACL, etc ...

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann By not working I mean the reasoner does not find inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found was to make the ontology "closed world", by making owl:Thing equivalent to the set of all individuals defined so far.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the meaning of `Object SubClassOf hasShape min 1 Shape` is that every individual of `Object` is associated with an individual of `Shape` via the `hasShape` property.

So if you create an individual `x` of type `Object` without `x` being associated with an individual of `Shape`, why does the reasoner not determine that your ontology is inconsistent? The reason for this is due to the **open world assumption**. Informally it means that the only inferences that the reasoner can make from an ontology is based on explicit information stated in the ontology or what can derived from explicit stated information.

When you state `x` is an `Object`, there is **no explicit information**  in the ontology that states that `x` is **not** associated with an individual of `Shape` via the `hasShape` property. To make explicit that `x` is not is such a relation, you have to define `x` as follows:

```
Individual: x
  Types: 
    Object,
    hasShape max 0 owl:Thing
```

Btw, this problem has nothing to do with identity as you stated.

Comment: So I'd have to assert the last statement "hasShape max 0 owl:Thing" whenever I create an individual of Object, and remove that statement when another individual of Shape is created and associated? This seems to require creating and managing additional logic outside of the ontology.

Comment: If you want your ontology to give an inconsistency when an individual of Object does not have a known relation to a Shape individual, this is what you will have to do using OWL and protege. Otherwise it may be worthwhile to consider using an RDF datastore and say SPIN or SHACL. It is difficult to say without knowing more about your usecase